# Error in implementing kernel's linked-list interface

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, linked-list, kernel

I am trying to use the linux's kernel implementation of linked list(list.h), but I keep getting the following error:-
invalid type argument of ->  (have 'int')

```
struct klist
{
 int data;
 struct list_head list;
};

int main()
{
 int i;
 struct klist *_lptr;
 LIST_HEAD(klist_head);
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
  _lptr=(struct klist*)malloc(sizeof(struct klist));
  _lptr->data=i;
 }
 list_for_each_entry(_lptr,&klist_head,list)
 {
  printf("%d\n",_lptr->data);
 }
}
```

Comment: it would be extremely useful to annotate the line for which this error was reported..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compiled and run your code, there is no error reported. (gcc 4.6.3, kubuntu 12.04)

I write one below too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

typedef struct klist{
    int data;
    struct list_head list;
}klist;

int main()
{
    LIST_HEAD(klist_head);

    /* allocate the list */
    int i = 0;
    klist *_lptr = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        _lptr = (klist*) malloc(sizeof(klist));
        _lptr->data = i;
        list_add(&_lptr->list, &klist_head);
    }

    /* print the list */
    list_for_each_entry(_lptr, &klist_head, list){
        printf("%d\n", _lptr->data);
    }

    /* free the list */
    struct list_head *pos = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    list_for_each_safe(pos, temp, &klist_head){
        _lptr = list_entry(pos, klist, list);
        list_del(pos);
        free(_lptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```